# Unable to login with python selenium error:NoSuchElementException error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, python-3.4

I have tried locating the submit button by id and xpath but none of them worked and checked in the page source ,the id is same.I have no idea why this is happening even though I am giving the correct Id or xpath
 
**URL :** https://moodle.niituniversity.in/moodle/login/index.php

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore")
driver.get("https://moodle.niituniversity.in/moodle/login/index.php")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("User123")
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("pass123")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='loginbtn']").click()
driver.get("https://moodle.niituniversity.in/moodle")
assert "user" in driver.page_source
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

> .NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='loginbtn']"}

Comment: Did you look for frame or iframe?? Make sure this button is not inside any frame or iframe??

Comment: Yes This is not in any iframe

Comment: And what about locator??? Also make sure there is only one element by provided Id `loginbtn`

Comment: Only one element with Id.Checked

Comment: tried with `driver.find_element_by_id("loginbtn")` didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be possible this is timing issue, you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until button present on page as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginbtn")))
element.click()
```

Full code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://moodle.niituniversity.in/moodle/login/index.php")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("User123")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("pass123")

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginbtn")))
button.click()
```

Comment: Why does this happen.?

Comment: This is happen mostly when your internet is slow to loading the page with element and driver execution is fast that's why selenium couldn't get the element..

Comment: @anderson What do you mean still not working?? Is there any exception??

Comment: I've tried `assert 'user' not in driver_source`.rises an assertion error