# Unable to log in with python selenium

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, moodle

I am trying to log in to my university Moodle account using Selenium and headless chrome.

I have managed to locate the "username" and "password" elements and I am pretty sure I fill them in the correct way.
the problem is when I click submit on the form objects (or manually click the submit button) it appears that the page won't acknowledge the data that was given.

the site is:
https://moodle2.cs.huji.ac.il/nu19/

and my code:

```
chromeBrow = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
chromeBrow.get(loginPage)


# login

nameObj = chromeBrow.find_element_by_id('login_username')
nameObj.clear()
nameObj.send_keys(userName)

passObj = chromeBrow.find_element_by_id('login_password')
passObj.clear()
passObj.send_keys(userPass)

wait = WebDriverWait(chromeBrow, 1000)

submit = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "loginbtn")))
passObj.submit()
```

I have tried using the WebDriverWait as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961190/unable-to-login-with-python-selenium-errornosuchelementexception-error), but I'm still logged out after the submission.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the last line, you should use:

```
    submit.click()
```

Instead of:

```
    passObj.submit()
```

??